# My program will not run, when instead of using a black background i try to use a image as background ERROR: pygame.surface' object is not callable

Tags: python, pygame

I tried to run this program, however this error comes up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/ComputingCW/ComputingCW.py", line 12, in <module>
    Surface = pygame.image.load('Pygame_Background.jpg')((W, H), 0, 32)
TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable
```

It used to be:
Surface = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H), 0, 32) and then using "Surface.fill(BLACK)" to make a black background.

I don't understand why won't it allow me to use a image as my background. Can someone please help me, and explain why is this happening.

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
# all_fonts = pygame.font.get_fonts()


W = 1280
H = 900

Surface = pygame.image.load('Pygame_Background.jpg')((W, H), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Physics in Motion')

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

game = True
mouse_pos = (0, 0)
mouse_click = (0, 0)
text1B = False
text2B = False
text3B = False
output = ''

while game == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
            mouse_pos = event.pos
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mouse_click = event.pos


    color = WHITE
    Font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 72)
    if text1B:
        color = RED
    text = Font.render('Start Simulation', True, color)
    text_rect = text.get_rect()
    text_rect.center = (W / 2, H / 5)
    if text_rect.collidepoint(mouse_click):
        output = 'Simulation()'
    if text_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        text1B = True
    else:
        text1B = False
    Surface.blit(text, text_rect)

    color = WHITE
    if text2B:
        color = RED

    Font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 72)
    text = Font.render('Graph Generator', True, color)
    text_rect = text.get_rect()
    text_rect.center = (W / 2, H * 2 / 5)
    if text_rect.collidepoint(mouse_click):
        output = 'GraphG()'
    if text_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        text2B = True
    else:
        text2B = False
    Surface.blit(text, text_rect)

    color = WHITE
    if text3B:
        color = RED

    Font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 72)
    text = Font.render('Exit', True, color)
    text_rect = text.get_rect()
    text_rect.center = (W / 2, H * 3 / 5)
    if text_rect.collidepoint(mouse_click):
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    if text_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        text3B = True
    else:
        text3B = False
    Surface.blit(text, text_rect)

    Font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 72)
    text = Font.render(output, True, BLUE)
    text_rect = text.get_rect()
    text_rect.center = (W / 2, H * 4 / 5)
    Surface.blit(text, text_rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
    mainClock.tick(100000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `pygame.image.load('Pygame_Background.jpg')` loads an image from your hard disk and turns it into a [`pygame.Surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object. Now you have this surface and try to call it like a function with parentheses behind it `((W, H), 0, 32)` and that causes the `TypeError`, because a surface object isn't a function (it's not callable).

What you actually want to do is:

1. Create the display window (I call it `screen` here).

   ```
   screen = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H), 0, 32)
   ```
2. Load the background image (better call it `background` because `Surface` is the name of the `pygame.Surface` class).

   ```
   background = pygame.image.load('Pygame_Background.jpg').convert()
   ```

   Also, call the `pygame.Surface.convert` or `convert_alpha` method to improve the performance.
3. Blit the `background` and everything else onto the screen in the main while loop.

   ```
   screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
   screen.blit(text, text_rect)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a name conflict. pygame.Surface is a module (or a sub module), but this line seems to overwrite this Surface object:

```
Surface = pygame.image.load('Pygame_Background.jpg')((W, H), 0, 32)
```

I would try to use different variable in the left hand side, for example surf_bg.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the absolute path of the file of `'Pygame_Background.jpg'`

Trace your directory starting from your Drive's letter